# How to resolve dpkg error code (1)?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I get the following apt-get error message:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python-gobject-2-dev (2.28.6-10ubuntu2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-gobject-2-dev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-gobject-2-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried all the tricks I know using apt-get and dpkg, but the error still exists.
I don't care if python is broken after after fixing the error.

Comment: I just fixed the problem with the Info from the following posting:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311627/dpkg-how-to-ignore-error-in-post-pre-scripts][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311627/dpkg-how-to-ignore-error-in-post-pre-scripts

Comment: You should answer the question, using those links and explaining the steps you took to solve it, and mark it as the answer.  This will properly resolve the question, and is clearer to others who may find this question later than a comment with some links in it.